# In Swift, can you create a protocol which requires a particular function only when certain conditions hold about the associated types?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, associated-types

I would like to express a Swift protocol similar to the following two snippets which both fail to compile.

Attempt 1:

```swift
protocol AbstractFunction {
    associatedtype Domain
    associatedtype Codomain

    func apply(_ x: Domain) -> Codomain

    static var identity: Self where Domain == Codomain { get }
}
```

Attempt 2:

```swift
protocol AbstractFunction {
    associatedtype Domain
    associatedtype Codomain

    func apply(_ x: Domain) -> Codomain

    static func identity() -> Self where Domain == Codomain { get }
}
```

The first is not even valid within the Swift grammar while the second fails with
`'where' clause cannot be attached to a non-generic declaration`.

Both of these examples try to express a protocol which describes functions which are not instances of an actual function type `(A) -> B`. If one has types `Vector2` and `Vector3`, one could imagine creating types `Matrix2x2`, `Matrix2x3`, and `Matrix3x3` and conforming them to the `AbstractFunction` protocol. The domain of `MatrixNxM` would be `VectorM` and the codomain would be `VectorN`. Square matrices have an identity matrix, but the concept of an identity matrix (or really identity function) does not make sense when the domain and codomain differ.

Consequently, I would like the protocol `AbstractFunction` to require conforming types to provide an identity, but only in the case where `Domain == Codomain`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by declaring second more strict protocol as:

```
protocol AbstractFunction {
    associatedtype Domain
    associatedtype Codomain

    func apply(_ x: Domain) -> Codomain
}

protocol AbstractEndofunction: AbstractFunction where Codomain == Domain {
    static var identity: Self { get }
}
```

Example on Int -> Int function:

```swift
final class IntFunction: AbstractEndofunction {
    typealias Domain = Int

    static var identity = IntFunction { $0 }

    private let function: (Int) -> Int

    init(_ function: @escaping (Int) -> Int) {
        self.function = function
    }

    func apply(_ x: Int) -> Int {
        return function(x)
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I want, but it's close. In my code, I have a struct `FreeVectorSpace<T>` and another struct `FreeLinearMap<T,S>` which is a wrapper for a function `(T) -> FreeVectorSpace<S>`. I would love to make `FreeLinearMap<T,S>` conform to just one protocol to cover both usages, but this enables me to use `extension FreeLinearMap: AbstractEndofunction where T == S`, which is pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. However, I can see two another ways that might help you out.

By using optional type to `identity` you indicate that a certain type that implements `AbstractFunction` may or may not have an identity. For instance:

```
final class ConcreteFunctionWithoutIdentity: AbstractFunction {
  typealias Domain = Int
  typealias Codomain = Int

  func apply(_ x: Int) -> Int {
    return 0
  }

  static var identity: ConcreteFunctionWithoutIdentity?
}

// Using
if let identity = ConcreteFunctionWithoutIdentity.identity else {
   // It will not fall here, since ConcreteFunctionWithoutIdentity doesn't have identity
   ...
}

final class ConcreteFunctionWithIdentity: AbstractFunction {
  typealias Domain = Int
  typealias Codomain = Int

  func apply(_ x: Int) -> Int {
    return 0
  }

  static var identity: ConcreteFunctionWithtIdentity? {
    // return something
  }
}

if let identity = ConcreteFunctionWithtIdentity.identity else {
   // It will fall here, since ConcreteFunctionWithIdentity indeed have identity
   ...
}
```